# how to test protocol conformance for optional struct

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Checking if the Struct conformed to protocol, but if the nested struct is optional it always returns `false`,

example:

```swift
protocol XYZ {

}

extension XYZ {
  func test() { 
     print("asdsfd") 
  } 
}

struct Test1: XYZ { 
  var test2: Test2 
  var test3: Test3?

  init(){
    self.test2 = Test2()
    self.test3 = Test3() 
  }
}

struct Test2: XYZ {

}

struct Test3: XYZ {

}
```

Now: if I want check if the struct is using protocol

```swift
let x = Test1()
```

below condition will be true because `Test2` conformed to `XYZ` protocol

```swift
print(type(of: x.test2) is XYZ.Type)
```

below condition will be false because `Optional<Test2>` conformed to  `XYZ` protocol should be `true` but it's return `false` because of optional

```swift
print(type(of: x.test3) is XYZ.Type)
```

how should I handle the optional in this case, I tried by unwrapping optional but it's not happening. any help is appreciated.

I tried to unwrap the optional but it's not happening. I am trying to find a way to compare the optional type conforms to protocol.

Comment: it's typo, corrected it.

Comment: please refresh, I corrected my code, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [The Swift Programming Language: Protocols: Checking for Protocol Conformance](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID283), in which the `is`, `as?` and `as!` operators can check for conformance directly, without needing to extract the `type(of:)`:

> **Checking for Protocol Conformance**
>
> You can use the `is` and `as` operators described in [Type Casting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html) to check
> for protocol conformance, and to cast to a specific protocol. Checking
> for and casting to a protocol follows exactly the same syntax as
> checking for and casting to a type:
>
> - The `is` operator returns `true` if an instance conforms to a protocol and
>   returns `false` if it doesn’t.
> - The `as?` version of the downcast operator returns an optional value of
>   the protocol’s type, and this value is `nil` if the instance doesn’t
>   conform to that protocol.
> - The `as!` version of the downcast operator forces the downcast to the
>   protocol type and triggers a runtime error if the downcast doesn’t
>   succeed.

So, rather than:

```swift
print(type(of: x.test2) is XYZ.Type) // true
print(type(of: x.test3) is XYZ.Type) // false
```

You can avoid `type(of:)` and test the conformance directly (which handles optionals):

```
print(x.test2 is XYZ)                // true
print(x.test3 is XYZ)                // true
```

Answer (score 1):

When checking for protocol conformance don't use `Protocol.Type`

```
protocol XYZ {

}

extension XYZ {
  func test() {
     print("asdsfd")
  }
}

struct Test1: XYZ {
  var test2: Test2
  var test3: Test3?

  init(){
    self.test2 = Test2()
    self.test3 = Test3()
  }
}

struct Test2: XYZ {

}

struct Test3: XYZ {

}

let x = Test1()

// does Test1 conform to XYZ?
print(x is XYZ)

// Does x.test2 conform to the protocol?
print(x.test2 is XYZ)

// Does x.test3 conform to the protocol?
print(x.test3 is XYZ)

// The above prints true, we're seeing if it can be an XYZ, but if we test like you do
print(x.test3 is XYZ.Type)
// This is false, as you said in your example.
```

In real coding scenarios you're going to be using

`if let example = x.test3 as? MyProtocol { ... }`

I can't think of a common scenario I've run into where I've ever needed to compare against a `Protocol.Type`.

Also, in this example at least, all this testing is not needed because the compiler knows ahead of time. To make an example where it wouldn't:

```
let y: Any = x.test3

if let y = y as? XYZ {
    print("Test")
}
```

Here the compiler doesn't know that y conforms to the protocol, as its type is `Any`, but we can try and cast it - which we can see does work.